# Getting the browser to use a specific name for file being downloaded

Tags: php, http-headers

I am having trouble getting the browser to prompt the user to save an image with the correct name.

- My web root directory is `/var/www/html`
- I have an image (.jpg) in `/var/www/client/image.jpg`

*These two things cannot be changed for a number of reasons*

I have a file, dImage.php, in `/var/www/html` where I am doing the following to get the browser to download, not view the file.

```
$fileName = '/var/www/client/image.jpg';    

header('Content-disposition: attachment; filename="' . $fileName . '"');
header('Content-type: image/jpeg');
readfile($fullpath);
```

In IE I get prompted to download **dImage.jpg**

In Firefox I get prompted to download **dImage.php** which is a: JPEG Image.  When I download the file there it's saved as a .php file which, once the extension is changed, opens aproperly as an image.

Is it possible for me to have the browser prompt the user to save the file as **image.jpg** regardless of the browser being used?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code you have shown will produce a file with a name of '/var/www/client/image.jpg' which is obviously not a valid file name, which is why your file gets named after the script.

`$fileName` is the desired name of the output file,
`$fullpath` should be the absolute path to the desired file, php's relative paths do not work like HTML's paths do. '/' will not point you to the document root folder.

Comment: So I changed my code to match yours and it initially didn't work but your initial answer said something about "You're not showing the complete code..." so I reread all the code to find that $fileName was not being set right.  Thanks.

Comment: @Jason It's always best to show full code, `it keeps the guesswork right out of it.` If sensitive information is not be viewed, it can always be replaced with dummy info, if I can say.